# Change Gemfile.lock build with version within gems installed via RubyGems

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, react-native

I am new to React & React Native. Currently, when I install gems via RubyGems, they get installed to `/s/iOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/<gemName>` path where `3.1.0` is the gem version I am using currently. **The issue is that their Gemfile.lock files are pointing to an old bundle version `1.17.3`**. Is there a way to update the bundle version in these Gemfile.lock files? The bundle version in my project's Gemfile.lock file is showing up as `2.4.13`.

`bundle update --bundler` only updates my project's Gemfile.lock file and not the nested dependencies' Gemfile.lock files

UPDATE:
IF I try to update these bundle versions manually, I get this error.

An error occurred while installing json (1.8.2), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
cocoapods was resolved to 0.36.3, which depends on
cocoapods-core was resolved to 0.36.3, which depends on
activesupport was resolved to 4.2.1, which depends on
json

Comment: Why do you care about the bundler version defined in the Gemfile.lock of a bundled gem? When installing a gem only the gem‘s dependencies in the gemspec file are considered.

Comment: Even I agree on that but these are getting called out my organisation's component governance check pipeline.

Comment: Then just delete those Gemfile.lock files from the gems. There are not needed and not used  when bundleing gems. And actually most guides tell to not include them into published gems. They are only used when developing the gem but not when using it. Or reconfigure your checks to ignore them.

Comment: Let me try the first one, as the second one is not in my control. Thanks. Will update if this works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change version in your **Gemfile** for that particular gem and then do **bundle install**. Currently I guess 3.1.0 is not your gem version but a ruby version.